# Split nvarchar in table

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a datatable which returns 300 rows of data. What I want to do is to find a specific column and split the content of that column where there is a "`<br />`" and then add an `<a href=...>` & `</a>` around each split and then return the same datatable.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
 Private Sub SplitCellsWithAnchor(ByVal dt As DataTable)

        Dim BroaderTerms As String() = dr.Item("BroaderMain").ToString.Trim.Split(CType("<br />", Char()))
        Dim Replace As String
        For Each b As String In BroaderTerms
            If b.Trim <> "" Then
                Replace = "<a href='' target='_blank'>" & b.Trim & "</a>"
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

From what I understand, I have to give it a datatable, but how to get that specific column I am not too sure - how should I do that?

Comment: You see that variable `dr`? Where does it come from? Also, you want `.Split({"<br />"}, StringSplitOptions.None)` to split on that string. (If the latter shows an error, please tell us which version of Visual Studio you're using.)

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that you have already gotten the data from the database and it is stored in a table called `MyDataTable` and the column name in the datatable is called `MyColumn`:

```
 ' Untested Code
 Dim MyListOfStrings as List(of String())
 For Each MyDataRow as DataRow in MyDataTable.Rows
    'Now you jsut access the column name and do what you need with it.
    Dim MyDtring as String = MyDataRow("MyColumn")
    If Not IsDbnull(MyString) Then ' Always check for null
        ' Because we don't know how many "<br /"'s there are, we loop through them all (untested code)
        Dim MyStringArray() as string = Split(MyString, "<br />")
        Dim x as Integer = 0
        While X <= MyStringArray.Length - 1
            MyStringArray(x) = "<a href='' target='_blank'>" & MyStringArray(x) & "</a>"
            x += 1
        Loop
        MyListOfStrings.Add(MyStringArray)
        ' When complete you will have 300 string arrays in the list of strings
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Great! After this i am trying to split the string at each <br/> tag .. and each split wrap in an a tag